# Nested for_each with lambda not possible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, stl, lambda

The following code does not compile in VS2012, it gives

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

on the line of the second for_each (line 4 below).

```
vector<string> v1;
for_each(begin(v1), end(v1), [](string s1) {
    vector<string> v2;
    for_each(begin(v2), end(v2), [](string s2) {
        cout << "...";
    });
});
```

I found some related stuff like http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560907/capturing-variables-in-nested-lambdas which shows a bug (they are doing something different) but on the other hand that shows that what I print above should be possible.

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Compiles fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8c937ecdeec793d200548b79dc5df4fb-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3). I guess this is a VC bug.

Comment: What puzzles me is that above link says it WORKS as long as you're not trying to capture the outer variable (which I don't in my example).

Comment: Compiles fine on VS2012 (I think it's with Nov 2012 CTP) [here](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/d7q)

Comment: Also compiles fine with the VC 2013 Preview.

Comment: @interjay: Could you check if it's really with Nov CTP?
I want to avoid the CTP as it gives weird errors and is a hassle with our buildsystem CMake.

Comment: It says it's using compiler version "VS2012CTP", which I assume refers to the Nov CTP.

Comment: Thanks. Then that guy in above link must all also have the CTP. (which seems a bit odd)